# eosio multisig exec problem

Tags: smart-contract, eosio-code, multisig

For multisig transaction, 
1. Firstly I have created two accounts(partner1 and partner2) with same key(EOS....HoCF)

> cleos create account eosio partner1
>   EOS8FE********HoCF 
>   cleos create account eosio partner2
>   EOS8FE********HoCF

2. Then I have a contract named *demo* with function meetup(just push data)

> cleos create account eosio demo EOS8FE********HoCF (with same key)

Key imported in default wallet
Then I followed the steps given below,

> cleos set account permission eosio.msig active '{"threshold":
>   1,"keys": [{"key":
>   "EOS8FE********HoCF","weight":
>   1}],"accounts":
>   [{"permission":{"actor":"demo","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}'
>   owner -p eosio.msig
>
> cleos multisig propose meetnow '[{"actor":
>   "partner2", "permission": "active"},{"actor": "partner1",
>   "permission": "active"}]' '[{"actor": "partner2", "permission":
>   "active"},{"actor": "partner1", "permission": "active"}]' demo meetup
>   '{"timestamp":12345648, "author":"partner1", "male":"yashu",
>   "female":"swap","ismet":"no"}' partner1 -p partner1
>
> cleos multisig review partner1 meetnow
>
> cleos multisig approve partner1 meetnow '{"actor":
>   "partner2","permission": "active"}' -p partner2

When am trying to exec ,getting following error

> cleos multisig exec partner1 meetnow -p partner1
>   getting following error,

```
Error Details:
transaction declares authority '{"actor":"partner2","permission":"active"}', but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 0 ms, provided permissions [{"actor":"eosio.msig","permission":"eosio.code"}], and provided keys []
```

eventhough am having keys in corresponding wallet.

Answer (score 2):

In the proposal, there are several issues:

1. The first bit of JSON where you specify the permissions has to be in alphanumeric order. i.e. partner1 has to come before partner2.
2. The second section of json should refer to the demo account, i.e. `'[{"actor":"demo", "permission":"active"}]'

For a detailed description of how to do msig with cleos, check out this tutorial: https://forums.eosgo.io/discussion/1004/eosio-multisig-tutorial